# Problema ejecutando comandos en un firewall Palo Alto vía CLI

Tags: nodejs, ssh

He desarrollado una aplicación con Node JS, su objetivo es conectarse a consolas UNIX/Linux via [SSH](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2), el código es el siguiente

```
console.log('Starting server...');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port',3000);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('listening on 3000');   
    var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

    var conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function() {
      console.log('Client :: ready');
        conn.exec('show system info | match uptime', function(err, stream) {
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
              console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
              conn.end();
            }).on('data', function(data) {
              console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
              console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
            });
      });
    }).connect({
      host: '10.10.10.10',
      port: 22,
      username: 'user',
      password: 'password',
      privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('C:\\Temp\\MyPrivateKey.ppk')
    });
})
```

El problema viene cuando al iniciar el servidor la aplicación se intenta conectar a un firewall de la marca Palo Alto pero no obtengo ninguna respuesta cuando algún comando es enviado. He intentado hacer la prueba conectándome a un servidor RedHat o CentOS y el comando es ejecutado y la respuesta se imprime en pantalla.

El resultado actual es:

```
Starting server...
listening on 3000
Fisrt test!
Client :: ready
```

El resultado esperado debería ser:

```
Starting server...
listening on 3000
Fisrt test!
Client :: ready 
uptime: 246 days, 15:40:05
```

El resultado lo sé porque porque conectándome al firewall vía Putty puedo ejecutar comandos y ver los resultados.

Nota: al mostrar en pantalla el `stream`, comparo el resultado que me da el servidor y el firewall, y uno de los parámetros que me da el RedHat es `_remoteVer: 'OpenSSH_7.4',`, y el firewall `_remoteVer: 'OpenSSH_12.1'`, pero es bastante extraño ya que la última versión del OpenSSH es 7.7/7.7p1 (released 2018-04-02), no comprendo por qué o si esto influya en el resultado esperado.

¿Es posible que me esté faltando algo o tenga algún error?

**Actualización:**

Probando otros componentes como [`node-ssh-exec`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh-exec) obtengo el mismo resultado, incluso usando otras tecnologías como [`SSH.NET`](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) en conjunto con C#.

Por un momento pensé que me hacía falta enviar un [*carriage return*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) con `\n`, `\r` o ambos `\r\n`, pero tampoco me funcionó:

`show system info | match uptime\n`

`show system info | match uptime\r`

`show system info | match uptime\r\n`

Comment: Me suena a que te falta el `privateKey` en el `connect()`.

Comment: @Kleith en el Putty no pongo `privateKey`, otra cosa es que en el firewall puedo ver el usuario conectado, es decir, la conexión se realiza pero no veo nada en el resultado

Comment: ¡Momento! en el Putty, la primera vez que te conectas, el Windows acepta una "llave"

Comment: @fredyfx ¿re refieres a [esto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD7vv.png)?

Comment: afirmativo, a eso me refiero :D

Comment: @Kleith he puesto el PrivateKey en la función `connect()` y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen principalmente dos puntos de mejora:

1. Es necesario escribir el `stream` con el comando que se ejecutará usando la función `.write()`
2. Habilitar el modo debug en el firewall con el comando `debug cli on`

Finalmente el código debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('listening on 3000');

    var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
    var conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function () {
        conn.exec('', function (err, stream) {
            console.log('Client :: ready');

            var cmd = 'show system info | match uptime';
            stream.write(cmd);

            if (err)
                throw err;
            stream.on('data', function (data, stderr) {
                if (stderr)
                    console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
                else
                {
                    var arr = data.toString().split('\n');
                    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                        console.log(arr[i]);
                }
            }).on('exit', function (code, signal) {
                console.log('Exited with code ' + code);
            });
            stream.end('\n');
        });
    }).connect({
        host: '10.10.10.10',
        port: 22,
        username: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('C:\\Temp\\MyPrivateKey.ppk')
    });
})
```

Esto nos genera el resultado esperado:

```
Starting server...
listening on 3000
Client :: ready 
uptime: 252 days, 19:01:36
```